# how to run an app developed on ionic on the android studio emulator

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to deploy my ionic app to the android studio and run it using the emulator. I have installed the android file into my ionic app. When I try to run it in android studio, this error shows up. Does anybody know why or did I miss out on anything to add to my project? Please help thanks!

Comment: where is your error message / image ?

Comment: Share Your Error and Steps you did to build your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the Ionic Developer Guide for Android - https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android

But to answer your question...

When you build an Ionic project, it generates an Android project (`platforms\android` on Cordova or `android` on Capacitor). Open this generated Android project in Android Studio. Then run it from there.